Laravel vite: import files convert to seperate files instead of bundle to one file
I used vite for my laravel project.
Problem is if I have a js file that import another file like this:
import axios from "axios"

Or
import {hide, show, validateInput} from './utils';

Vite will create separate files for utils and axios and require them in final js files!
But I want to have all code in final file without require.
Tried mutli ways, but no change.
This is my vite.config.js file.
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: {
                appJs: 'resources/js/app.js',
                register: 'resources/js/register.js',
                oauthLogin: 'resources/js/oauth-login.js',
                registerPage: 'resources/vue/pages/register/app.ts',
                app: 'resources/css/app.css',
            },
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrlsOptions: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            }
        }),
        viteSassDts(),
        vitePluginIgnore(),
        fixFontPaths(),
        watchBuild()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/vue')
        },
        extensions: ['.vue', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                postcssImport,
                tailwindcss,
                autoprefixer
            ],
        },
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ['@typescript-eslint/parser', 'eslint', 'typescript'],
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'public',
        emptyOutDir: false,
        rollupOptions: {
            inlineDynamicImports: true,
            output: {
                entryFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
                    if (chunkInfo.name === 'registerPage')
                        return 'js/pages/register/app.js'
                    if (chunkInfo.name === 'appJs')
                        return 'js/app.js'
                    return 'js/[name].js';
                },
                assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
                    if (/\.(css|scss)$/.test(name ?? '')) {
                        return 'css/[name].[ext]';
                    }
                    return 'assets/[name].[ext]';
                },
            },
            manualChunks: {
                fonts: ['./public/fonts/']
            }
        },
    },
    server: {
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        }
    },
    publicDir: 'public'
})

